# Intentando recrear el comando ls -l en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

desde hace tiempo he estado creando un simulador de bash en windows usando python, en este momento estoy programando el comando:

```
ls -l
```

el problema es que no se de que manera pueda hacer que se impriman los siguientes datos del archivo o carpeta:

- permisos
- usuario
- fecha de creación

muchas gracias por su atención.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo siguiente muestra cómo extraer la información que buscas, a través de `os.stat()`, y cómo formatearlo para darle un aspecto similar al de `ls -l`.

En concreto:

- Uso el módulo [`pwd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pwd.html) para extraer el nombre del usuario, a partir de su `uid`.
- Uso el módulo [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) para formatear la fecha y hora de la última modificación
- Incluyo una función `sizeof_fmt()` para formatear el tamaño de forma similar a como hace el flag `-h` de `ls` (dando unidades de tamaño más legibles para personas, en lugar de usar bytes).

Para una simulación más fiel de `ls` aún necesitarías mostrar el grupo y los permisos de lectura-escritura. Esa información también te la da `os.stat`.

Este es mi código:

```
import time
import os
import pwd

def sizeof_fmt(num):
    for unit in ['B', 'K', 'M', 'G']:
        if num < 1024:
            return "%3.1f%s" % (num, unit)
        num /= 1024.0
    return "%3.1f%s" % (num, 'T')

def format_file(filename, dirname=''):
    _stat = os.stat(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
    tamano = sizeof_fmt(_stat.st_size)
    propietario = pwd.getpwuid(_stat.st_uid)[0]
    modificado = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", time.localtime(_stat.st_mtime))
    ret = "%8s %10s %s %s" % (
            propietario, tamano, modificado, filename
            )
    return ret

for filename in sorted(os.listdir(".")):
    print(format_file(filename))
```

Ejemplo de salida:

```
root     188.0K 2015-08-17 07:10 zip
root      84.2K 2015-08-17 07:10 zipcloak
root      47.3K 2018-04-05 14:48 zipdetails
root       2.9K 2015-11-20 15:41 zipgrep
root     158.9K 2015-11-20 15:41 zipinfo
root      79.9K 2015-08-17 07:10 zipnote
root      79.9K 2015-08-17 07:10 zipsplit
root     265.0B 2016-02-07 18:59 zxpdf
```